# Is there an advantage to having cellulite

Tags: human-biology, structural-biology

There are many ads nowadays advertising cellulite removal, and it causes me to wonder if there is an advantage to having cellulite or if it is just a result of too much fat unevenly spread?  Is it structurally more efficient at storing energy or providing insulation?

Answer (score 1):

There's no advantage or disadvantage (beyond personal perception of attractiveness).

It's a benign condition that can occur with hormone changes, weight changes, and *especially* genetic predisposition.

It occurs in most women (up to 90% will have it at some point) and some men, and physicians consider it 'normal.'

http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/cellulite/DS00891